# ASP.NET MVC to setup outbound routing for combined folder-like and url-parameters-like url addreses

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have controller/action:

```
public partial class MyControllerController : Controller {

  public virtual ActionResult Index(string name, string category, DateTime? from = null, DateTime? to = null)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

And I want that my URLs look like this:

```
/MyController/myname/mycategory
/MyController/myname/mycategory?from=10%2F01%2F2013%2000%3A00%3A00&to=10%2F31%2F2013%2023%3A59%3A59
```

I have tried following route registration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "MyRoutes",
  "MyController/{name}/{category}/",
  new
  {
    controller = "MyController",
    action = "Index",
    from = UrlParameter.Optional,
    to = UrlParameter.Optional
  });
```

It accepts incoming URL, but it is not generating correct outbound URL when using `Url.Action()` method. My `Url.Action()` always returns address like:

```
/CouponManager?name=myname&category=mycategory&from=08%2F01%2F2013%2000%3A00%3A00&to=08%2F31%2F2013%2023%3A59%3A59
```

Anybody can help ?

Comment: You can't do what you're trying to do. You have too many parameters to accept them in the format you'd like to, that's why it's turning it into a query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Url.RouteUrl`.  For example:

```
Url.RouteUrl("MyRoutes", new { name = "myname", category = "mycategory" })
```

Or

```
Url.RouterUrl("MyRoutes", new { name = "myname", category = "mycategory", from = fromDate, to = toDate })
```

Also, remove from and to in your route definition, so that it reads as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "MyRoutes",
  "MyController/{name}/{category}/",
  new
  {
    controller = "MyController",
    action = "Index"
  });
```

You can choose to list name and category as optional parameters in your route or give them default values, but from and to don't belong in there unless you use them as part of the url route and not as query strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your URL like
 /MyController/myname/Catagory?.., you should have an action by the name of myname in MyController  which takes an argument of Catagory.